# Print with multithreads in one line

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I want to print in one line with multithreads. I created a class which creates a new thread to print it:

```
class Printer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, count1, count2):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.count1 = count1
        self.count1 = count1

    def run(self):
        while True:
            to_print = '\rCount1: {}      Count2: {}'.format(self.count1, self.count1)
            sys.stdout.write(to_print)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(5)
```

Then I run it via:

```
class ThreadPool(object): 
    def __init__(self,args):

    for _ in range(num_threads):
        worker = Worker(self.__queue) #Worker is a class run some tasks.
        if False is worker.isAlive():
            worker.setDaemon(True)
            worker.start()

    s = ThreadWriterSuccess(self.__write_q, 'success.txt')
    s.setDaemon(True)
    s.start()

    f = ThreadWriterFailed(self.__failed_q, 'failed.txt')
    f.setDaemon(True)
    f.start()

    p = Printer(s.counter, f.counter)
    p.setDaemon(True)
    p.start()

class ThreadWriterSuccess(threading.Thread):
    "Write Success"

    def __init__(self, queue, outputPath):
        self.q = queue
        self.outputPath = outputPath
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.counter = 0

    def run(self):
        """
        Write data in queue to file
        :return: None
        """
        while True:
            toWrite = self.q.qsize()
            self.counter += toWrite
            outputFile = open(self.outputPath, 'a+')
            for i in range(toWrite):
                data = self.q.get()
                content = 'SUCCESS | {0}\n'.format(data)
                outputFile.write(content)
                self.q.task_done()
            outputFile.close()
            time.sleep(10)


class ThreadWriterFailed(threading.Thread):
    "Write failed"

    def __init__(self, queue, outputPath):
        self.q = queue
        self.outputPath = outputPath
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.counter = 0

    def run(self):
        """
        Write data in queue to file
        :return: None
        """
        while True:
            toWrite = self.q.qsize()
            self.counter += toWrite
            # print('Die: {}'.format(self.counter), end='\r')
            outputFile = open(self.outputPath, 'a+')
            for i in range(toWrite):
                data = self.q.get()
                content = 'FALSE: | {0}\n'.format(data)
                outputFile.write(content)
                self.q.task_done()
            outputFile.close()
            time.sleep(5)
```

Note: `s.counter` and `f.counter` is a value in the `ThreadWriterSuccess` and `ThreadWriterFailed` classes.

However, when I run a program, the Printer class only runs and prints in the first time. It is not running again. How I can fix this? Thanks.

Comment: I _think_ I know what the problem is, but please provide an actual [mcve] before I start writing my answer. There are too many undefined variables in this code.

Comment: Hi, I updated it.

Comment: You would probably have better luck using something like `curses` to address the terminal directly, rather than just writing to standard output.

Comment: You kind of made it worse. Now it's just a bunch of classes, but no code that ever instantiates those classes or does anything with them. It's also a bit too long to be called a _minimal_ complete verifiable example.

Comment: Anyway, the problem I see is that your `Printer` keeps printing `self.count1`, but nobody ever _updates_ that attribute. You assign a value to it in the constructor, and then never again. So it prints the same value forever.

Comment: How I can get and update the counting from another class?

Comment: That's backwards. Your `Printer` should have an object (like a `ThreadWriterFailed` instance) _instead_ of the `count1` attribute. Then you can just print `self.threadwriter.counter`.

Comment: I try `class Printer(threading.Thread, ThreadWriterFailed, ThreadWriterSuccess)`. However, both `ThreadWriterFailed` and `ThreadWriterSuccess` need some inputs and I got error when use  `ThreadWriterSuccess.counter`. Can you give for me a full code please. Thanks.